# Accessing Hive Tables from Spark SQL when Data is Stored in Object Storage

Tags: apache-spark, hive, object-storage

I am using spark dataframe writer to write the data in internal hive tables in parquet format in IBM Cloud Object Storage.
So , my hive metastore is in HDP cluster and I am running the  spark job from the HDP cluster. This spark job writes the data to the IBM COS in parquet format.
This is how I am starting the spark session

```
SparkSession session = SparkSession.builder().appName("ParquetReadWrite")
                                .config("hive.metastore.uris", "<thrift_url>")
                                .config("spark.sql.sources.bucketing.enabled", true)
                                .enableHiveSupport()
                                .master("yarn").getOrCreate();
session.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.cos.mpcos.iam.api.key",credentials.get(ConnectionConstants.COS_APIKEY));
session.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.cos.mpcos.iam.service.id",credentials.get(ConnectionConstants.COS_SERVICE_ID));
session.sparkContext().hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.cos.mpcos.endpoint",credentials.get(ConnectionConstants.COS_ENDPOINT));
```

The issue that I am facing is that when I partition the data and store it (via partitionBy) I am unable to access the data directly from spark sql

```
spark.sql("select * from partitioned_table").show
```

To fetch the data from the partitioned table , I have to load the dataframe and register it as a temp table and then query it.
The above issue does not occur when the table is not partitioned.
The code to write the data is this

```
dfWithSchema.orderBy(sortKey).write()
                                .partitionBy("somekey")
                                .mode("append")
                                .format("parquet")
                                .option("path",PARQUET_PATH+tableName )
                                .saveAsTable(tableName);
```

Any idea why the the direct query approach is not working for the partitioned tables in COS/Parquet ?

Answer (score 0):

To read the partitioned table(created by Spark), you need to give the absolute path of the table as below.

```
selected_Data=spark.read.format("parquet").option("header","false").load("hdfs/path/loc.db/partition_table")
```

To filter out it further, please try the below approach.

```
selected_Data.where(col("column_name")=='col_value').show()
```

Comment: I do not want to use the spark.load api to load the data and then query it.  When the partitioned hive table is stored inside HDFS , I can query the table directly through spark.sql("select statement"). But I have the data stored in COS .If I run a spark sql directly as a select statement its not returning any rows

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs when the property  hive.metastore.try.direct.sql is set to true on the HiveMetastore configurations and the SparkSQL query is run over a non STRING type partition column.

For Spark, it is recommended to create tables with partition columns of STRING type.

If you are getting below error message while filtering the hive partitioned table in spark.

```
Caused by: MetaException(message:Filtering is supported only on partition keys of type string)
```

recreate your hive partitioned table with partition column datatype as string, then you would be able to access the data directly from spark sql.

else you have to specify the absolute path of your hdfs location to get the data incase your partitioned column has been defined as varchar.

```
selected_Data=spark.read.format("parquet").option("header","false").load("hdfs/path/loc.db/partition_table")
```

However I was not able to understand, why it's differentiating in between a varchar and string datatype for partition column